# Alternative to calling the Loaded method explicitly for dynamically created instances of a VCL component in Delphi 6?

Tags: delphi, vcl

I have several custom VCL components that do important tasks in their override of the TComponent Loaded() method.  This creates a nuisance when creating instances dynamically since the Loaded() method is not called by the Delphi global loader during run-time, like it does for components that were placed on forms/frames at design-time.  I also have to place the Loaded override in the *public* section of the class declaration so whatever code that creates an instance of the component can call it.  Finally I have to remember to call Loaded() for dynamically created instances or subtle bugs will creep into the application, a problem that has bit me several times already.

Is there a better solution or approach to this?

Comment: If you don't need to wait until the properties have been streamed in then you can override AfterConstruction.

If you do need to wait until the properties have been streamed in then you are going to have to do it manually just as you currently do. Because otherwise there's no way for the component to know that you have finished your assignment of the properties in runtime code.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of `Loaded`. It's called immediately after the component *is streamed in from the .dfm*; it has nothing to do with runtime or designtime. (IOW, it has nothing to do with setting properties at runtime, since that's not what it's supposed to do.) The reason it works for controls/frames dropped on the form at designtime is that they're present during the streaming process (they're in the .dfm as it's "loaded".) You should never be *calling* `Loaded` yourself under any circumstances I can imagine.

Comment: @Ken What other mechanism is there for actions that need to run after properties have been streamed? I agree that any customisation that Robert does should be broken out from Loaded into a separate method and then called from Loaded.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `AfterConstruction()` is called immediately after all constructors have exited, before any DFM streaming occurs, so it is called too soon to usually differentiate between streaming and dynamically creating, unless an `Owner` was passed to the constructor, in which case you can check if the `Owner` is being streamed or not.

Comment: @remy yes, I think I already said that

Comment: @David, the proper mechanism to be run after your properties have been *streamed* is `Loaded`. Robert's not talking about after *streaming*, but after manually constructing at runtime. (Sorry for the late edit - I hit Save and then re-read what you'd written.) The proper solution, IMO, is what you said - a separate method that can be called both at the end of your overridden `Loaded` and after creating at runtime and setting any necessary properties.

Comment: @KenWhite Robert is not talking about wanting to code stuff there. He's talking about components (writers) that (stupidly) assume that everybody always slaps their controls on a form/datamodule and do stuff in Loaded that shouldn't be done there. He wants to know how to solve this when instantiating these controls at run-time (versus slapping them on at design-time) _without_ having explicitely to call Loaded. He is in fact trying to achieve exactly what you are advocating.

Comment: @Marjan, that's not how I'm reading it. Perhaps Robert can clarify?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to call Loaded in your code you're doing it wrong. If you depend on a third party control that does, then I would fix that person's control. See below for how.

Let me make up a hypothetical example: Suppose I had 5 published properties, which once they are all loaded, can generate a complex curve or even better, generate a fractal, something that takes a long time.

At designtime I want to preview this curve, as soon as it's loaded, but I don't want the curve to be recalculated 5 times during DFM streaming, because each parameter P1 through P5 (type Double) has a SetP1 method, which invokes a protected method called Changed, and rebuilds my curve. Instead I have the SetP1 method return if csDesigning or csLoading are in the component states, and I then invoke Changed once, from Loaded.  Clearly I can't rely on property setter methods alone, in all cases, to invoke all changes.  So I need Loaded to tell me to do my first generation of some expensive work, that I want to be done 1 time exactly, not N times, where N is the number of DFM properties that would have been loaded that had method set procedures that invoked a method named Changed or something like that.

In your case, at runtime, you should not be relying on Loaded getting invoked at all. You should be instead, having your property set methods call Changed.  If you need some way to change multiple properties at once, and then do some expensive thing only once, then implement a TMyComponent.BeginUpdate/TMyComponent.EndUpdate type of method call, and avoid extra work.

I can think of NO useful places where doing something from Loaded makes any sense, except for cases like the ones above, which should be specific to designtime and DFM based class use.  I would expect a properly designed TComponent or TControl to properly initialize itself merely by being created in code, and by having its properties set.

So for my hypothetical TMyFractal component, I would do this when creating it in code without it ever having used DFM loading, or invoking Loaded:

```
  cs := TMyFractal.Create(Self);
  cs.Parent := Self; {Parent to a form}
  cs.Align := alClient;
  cs.BeginUpdate;
  cs.P1 := 1.03;  // does NOT trigger Regenerate
  cs.P2 := 2.3;
  cs.P3 := 2.4;
  cs.P4 := 2.5;
  cs.EndUpdate; // triggers expensive Regenerate method .
  cs.Show; 

  // later someone wants to tweak only one parameter and I don't want to make them
  // call regenerate:
  cs.P5 := 3.0; // Each param change regenerates the whole curve when not loading or in a beginupdate block.
```

In my TMyFractal.Change method, I would invoke the expensive RegenerateCurve method once, each time any coefficient P1-P4 is modified at runtime, after initial setup, and once exactly when the component is streamed in from DFM, where Loaded is only used to handle the fact that I can hardly expect to do a beginupdate/endupdate in my control like I would have done in the code above.